# Не работает оператор &&

Tags: javascript

Я хочу чтобы отправка формы не происходила если сама форма пустая.

```js
const regForm = document.forms[0];
const userLogin = regForm.inputLogin,
userPassword = regForm.inputPassword,
userRetypePassword = regForm.inputPasswordRetype;


regForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){

    if(!userLogin.value && !userPassword.value){
        console.log("Type login");
        event.preventDefault()
    } else {
      console.log('отправлено') || event.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
<input type='text' name='inputLogin' value=''>
<input type='text' name='inputPassword' value=''>
<button type='submit'>Кнопка</button>
</form>
```

Я думал использовать оператор && чтобы не растягивать код но почему то отправка формы происходит если она пустая. Без && оператора отправка формы не происходит если поле username не заполнено
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выведите перед if значения и посмотрите, что там лежит.

Comment: @SwaD значение пустое

Comment: Мне и детям тоже нравится фильм "Гарри Поттер", однако чудес не бывает. Если код не попадает в if, значит условия вернули false, а это может быть только в том случае, если хотя бы одно из значений не пустое(не пустая строка, не 0)! Если в value строка из пробела, то условие !some.value выдаст false. Так что внимательно смотрите, какие значения передаются и обрабатываются

Comment: уточните, что значит пустая. Насколько можно видеть, если оба поля одновременно вообще пустые - то форма не отправляется. А иные случаи - это уже нужно уточнять, в частности пробелы или только 1 поле не пустое.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` конечно работает.
Просто вы написали странное. У вас сейчас в коде условие «если нет одновременно ни логина ни пароля», а вы хотите «если нет хотя бы одного». Или, в переводе на русский «если нет логина или нет пароля».

Вот так всё работает:

```js
const regForm = document.forms[0];

regForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (!this.inputLogin.value || !this.inputPassword.value) {
    console.log("Type login and password");
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  console.log('будет отправлено');
  // в примере не отправляем, потому что всё равно некуда
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' name='inputLogin' value=''>
  <input type='password' name='inputPassword' value=''>
  <button type='submit'>Кнопка</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете более точно описать конкретную проблему. Я считаю что более правильно использовать логический оператор ||, потому что форма будет отправлена только когда все формы не являются пустыми. Также стоит добавить метод trim(), он убирает все пробелы в полях вода. После этого данный код будет работать замечательно!

```js
regForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){

if(!userLogin.value.trim() || !userPassword.value.trim()){
    console.log("Type login");
    event.preventDefault()
} else {
  console.log('отправлено') || event.preventDefault()
}
});
```

Comment: Ввели логин, не ввели пароль и форма отправится ) ввели лонин пробел и форма отправится. Ввели пароль, не вводя логин - аналогично )

Comment: Посмотрите на обновленный код в данном ответе, надо было лишь добавить метод trim() для удаления лишних пробелов! Если я решил вашу проблему попрошу поставить что мой ответ является  верным!

Comment: If отработает, если будет заполнено что то одно. Так что trim() ничего не меняет

Comment: Я все проверил, работает так как было задумано